# A Way to Group URLs

Tags: regex, url, cluster-analysis

I have a list of URLs, each associated with a set of numbers. For example:

```
http://example.com/ - 0
http://example.com/login/ - 1
http://example.com/login/verify/ - 2
http://example.com/user123/home/ - 3
http://example.com/user254/home/ - 3
http://example.com/user123/edit/ - 4
```

I want some method to 'compress' this, maybe using regexp -- the catch is that for all URLs not in the list I can assume they map to whatever number I want.

So an output like this -- any URL is checked against each expression *in this order*, and given a number according to the first match.

```
http://example.com/login/verify* - 2
http://example.com/login/* - 1
http://example.com/*/home/ - 3
http://example.com/*/edit - 4
http://example.com/* - 0
```

***Note:*** There are multiple possible outputs like this that are acceptable.  Also, I considered something like a tree, where each node contains an expression like one of the above, and the leaves at the end are the actual URLs to check against.

Another Note, I said mapped to numbers for simplicity's sake. Actually, they are mapped to a set of numbers, where the set has to match. Just in-case that helps someone come up with a solution (though I doubt it).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it will be easiest to use a different regex for each URL match, they would probably look something like this.

```
http://example\.com/login/verify
http://example\.com/login
http://example\.com/[^/]+/home
http://example\.com/[^/]+/edit
http://example\.com
```

Try to match the URL to each of these in order, then when it matches look up the number (or set) that corresponds to that match.

Alternatively you could use a single regex with capturing groups to determine which URL was actually matched, for example:

```
http://example\.com(?:(/login/verify)|(/login)|(/[^/]+/home)|(/[^/]+/edit))?
```

Here is a Rubular that shows how you could use the previous regex:
http://www.rubular.com/r/tklqMs8U1Z

**edit**: Here is a Python function that does what I think you're looking for.

```
import re

def url_match(url):
    base = "http://example.com"
    endings = [("/login/verify", 2), ("/login", 1), ("/*/home", 3), ("/*/edit", 4), ("", 0)]
    re_endings = ["(%s)" % re.escape(x[0]).replace(r"\*", "[^/]+") for x in endings]

    pattern = re.compile("%s(?:%s)" % (re.escape(base), "|".join(re_endings)))
    match = pattern.match(url)

    if match is None:
        return None

    index = [i for i, x in enumerate(match.groups()) if x is not None]
    return endings[index[0]][1]

url_match("http://example.com")              # 0
url_match("http://example.com/login")        # 1
url_match("http://example.com/login/verify") # 2
url_match("http://example.com/user123/home") # 3
url_match("http://example.com/user123/edit") # 4
url_match("http://sample.com")               # None
```

Comment: But the list of URL-number pairs I have is dynamically generated, so I need an automated way to generate the grouping.

Comment: It would help to know what language this is in if you need more than just a regex for the example you gave.

Comment: I'm not locked in to any language, this will be a standalone utility that interacts with the rest of my system via messages.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is clustering of the URL based on the webpath. You can check out K-means clustering of text document . It does explain this in details.

Comment: I tried looking at a couple of K-means papers, but I didn't find anything that suited this. Can you provide a more specific solution, or maybe a link?